# connect etimedout while installing a package via NPM

Tags: npm

I am getting:

> request to http://registry.npmjs.org/signalr-client-react failed,
>   connect etimedout 10.16.27.34.443

when i am trying to: `npm install @aspnet/signalr`

please help me here what to do

Comment: did you try to ping the address to check if it is even accessible from your network

Comment: I am getting Request timed out, when i am trying to ping the ip

Comment: This means your machine cannot connect to the server, check with your network team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ravi, Consider this:

```
npm config rm proxy 
npm config rm https-proxy
npm install signalr-client-react
```

The problem is possibly cosed because of Proxy issues you have with NPM at your machine, this will clean there configurations and attepmt to install the package again.

Comment: i am connected to the client VPn so proxy needed..so if i remove it will be fine ?

Comment: It will only affect NPM configurations.

Comment: Since you are using VPN connection, this may fail, if it did, you may wanna try disconnecting from it if possible, install the package, and then connect back with it.

Comment: i tried in my local it is working fine, but when i try to install same in my staging server it is showing same error...can you help me here

Comment: no i tried the commands which you shared ..but in server it is showing timedout..

Comment: possibly because the sandbox machine is not allowed to connect to internet

Comment: anything can do for this case @Lalit Mehra

Comment: i tried to install expo init hello-world i  am getting below error ? Choose a template: expo-template-blank
request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.27.35:443
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.@SultanH.